# Laravel Eloquent - Fetch data only if there is a match with data one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, eager-loading

I have a one to many relation setup.

A Customer can have many Students, students can have a status as either Full or Left.

I want to fetch the Customer only if they have Students that are FULL.

I thought Eager Loading would do the trick but it is still returning customers if they have no Full students:

```
$customers = Customer::with(array('students' => function($query)
    {
      $query->where('STATUS', '=', 'FULL');
    }))->get();
```

Have had a hunt around on Google but couldn't find anything, not really sure how to word this question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: does the customer also have a status field?

Comment: Nope, the customer always exists (in this case they are a Parent). They have no field to determine their status. Stuck with the table structure also so no modifications can be made to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just selecting what relations to pull back with that query. What you want is to select the customers **where** a relation has some property

Try:

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas('students', function($q) {
    $q->where('STATUS', '=', 'FULL');
})->get();
```

Further reading:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations